# How far would science and technology be without wars and religion?

Tags: alternate-history, technological-development

In an alternate reality a highly developped species, let's call them 3Os, found planet earth just before the neolithic revolution. Upon studying humans, they correctly predicted their social evolution up to present date. The 3Os were only half satisfied with the outcome, as they wanted humanity to have reached the state it's in today way sooner.

In their analysis they found many reasons for the slow development: readiness for violence, religious belief, racism etc. So they started to drug all humans on earth through air and water. The drug (that affects only humans) had to be administred continuously into the athmosphere. As a result, humans fought almost no wars, nations and people were more likely to unite and share ressources, and only peaceful religions prevailed. On the hand humans were no longer hostile to the environment and decided to limit demographic expansion.

Question: How long until science and technology is able to discover the artificial origin of the drug administred by the 3Os?

Additional information: humans will end up detecting the drug by it's chemical structure and pattern. They will understand how it affects the brain and that it was designed especially for humans. They will also conclude, that it's started to rain down, just before the neolethic revolution. Following these steps they will discover invisible clouds in the sky, which were producing the drug automatically. The clouds are controlled by a computer on the Moon. How long until science can confirm all of this?

Comment: You act as if conflict slowed down human development, when the opposite is true. Progress is *driven* by necessity, and there's no greater necessity than someone trying to kill you.

Comment: This is a valid point, but thousands of illnesses and natural disasters are still killing humans, you act as if the drug made nature kind too.

Comment: Humans developed science and technology *because* Adam and Eve ate the [fruit of the tree of knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_the_knowledge_of_good_and_evil) and were expelled from Paradise. If they had remained childlike and innocent they would have staid forever in the Garden of Eden and would never developed science and technology. (And I have no idea what a "peaceful religion" could be, and how would it be different from any normal religion.)

Comment: I agree, the most likely outcome is a peaceful, stalled out society where all problems are "solved" by cooperation and harmony. Advancement is seen as disruptive and chaotic. I'd guess a sort of utopian version of ancient Greece.

Comment: You've got your effects mixed up, yes dominant religions may well hamper scientific advances, particularly those that don't align with their internal narratives . but wars have always been observed to have the exact opposite effect, science and particularly any appropriately useful applications of technology nearly always see significant advances during times of war .. consider that a challenge to one of your assumptions, you need to rethink them, because you have that one completely and utterly wrong

Comment: How is this drug continuously administered over the course of tens of thousands of years, or is is a genetic change? Do they even have the aggression to defend themselves? Kill animals?

Comment: Most of your setting is based on the assumption that religion and war are usually what causes technology to stall, when we know that times of potential or direct military conflict are usually the times when technology advances the most (and not only is religion not always against technological progress, it's at times what triggers said wartimes). Furthermore, you're essentially asking us to rewrite human history almost entirely. Essentially: it's currently pretty opinion-based and a bit too broad (one could easily write an answer big enough to fill a book)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it fails "the book test": If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Comment: NOTE: human advancement is and always has been a function of *problem solving.* Where there is no problem to solve, there is no advancement. Don't let modern behaviors fool you. Today we sometimes make advancements for no better reason than to answer the question, "what if?" But that's a luxury that comes with prosperity. We celebrate gentleman-innovators like Newton and believe he could exist without the wars and biases... except that isn't actually true. We only think it could be because we're artificially removing him from the context of his life.

Comment: For more information, read my answers to [Technological Progression over 1,000 Years](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/203835/40609) and [Everyday life in a world and civilization which do not have any money in the economy ( and not barter too)](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/216692/40609).

Comment: While you don't need wars to address and solve problems, I do think you might want to examine the history of religion and science more closely. Especially in the West. It's not all Creationism! Take a look into the development of the university, the hospital and the evolution of the sciences from their somewhat mystical beginnings into a system of rational thought. I think we would be very far behind where we are now without the Church and unique religion it teaches.

Comment: Religion and natural philosophy (which is what ancient 'science' was before scientific method) went hand in hand. The average farmer, king, or soldier didn't care about exact motions of the stars, except for navigation. Priests did. The only 'blue skies' research that was done, was done for religious reasons.

Comment: Cooperation is always more advantageous than competition, contrary to popular belief. It's popular belief because the dominant classes in society want us to believe that competition is natural and advantageous, and they justify their place above us in society by saying they earned it - through competition. In reality, science has boomed in recent decades due to the sharing of information - due to cooperation. Likewise, religious people have a biased defense of organized religion, but history has proven that religion stifles innovation if it contradicts the religion's traditional teachings.

Comment: Since my question was closed I made an extensive research of my own. It appears to be a common misconception, at least here, that war is necessary for progress. The most important technological inventions and scientific discoveries and also the least important ones are not children of wars. Ilnesses, natural disasters, everyday problems, curiosity and economic during times of peace and stability are the real factors behind progress. 2ndly, while the causes of wars are always multi-factorial, without religious dogma, we would certainly have had fewer wars. All of this is proved historically.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer  A very long time maybe even never.  competition is essential technological development  War in particular since technology forward by leaps and bounds.

There are lots of examples in history Of large  empires that Starting with a technological advantage  But fell into stagnation due being at peace  for too long And suddenly  Wakeing up and realizing that they're more warlike neighbors  Who were hundreds of years behind them were now decades ahead. ( This is one of the reasons why the Chinese had gunpowder but Never guns).

Even peaceful technological development is typically motivated by competition. Tech companies don't push themselves else to constantly come out with a new And better products because there board they do it to keep ahead of the competition.  This is why large monopolies often slows down technological development.

They say necessity is the mother of all invention. But the truth is without competition It's actually really easy to get your needs meant without developing a high level of technology.

If all you need  Is enough food to live on,  A partner to provide emotional and sexual support, A community to be a part in,  And a sense of purpose to live for, Then you can have all this with basically stone age technology.

Also how are you humans limiting Demographic expansion Without modern technology?  And how would they even know that limiting demographic expansion is a good thing?  Apart from just being more peaceful this sounds like someone's transporting  knowledge from the future to the humans that's the only way this makes sense.